# Is Blender a fitting tool for creating batches of images

Tags: animation

I am currently using 3ds max and I am not very happy with its performance (taking too much time), so I am wonderin if Blender will be a more fitting program for my problem:

I will have one object in the scene which will be moved randomly and then an image should be rendered, including the Z-Buffer image.

This procedure must be repeated roughly 2 million times.

Should I go to Blender for this problem, or is a different Rendering software better for this problem?

Comment: Without knowing more details as it stands this is subject to opinion. The good news is Blender is free so there is no cost (other than time) to just download it and give it a run to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: You can create an animation sequence where each frame has a different location for the object. Then use the compositor to generate 2 images - one for the rendering, the other for the z-map. To generate 2 million images, the total time required will be the time to render one frame in the animation times 2 million. By working with rendering settings, the process can be sped up. By running on multiple machines it can be sped up more.  You can also render using the internal render for more speed. If you can render 10 frames a second, it will take about 2 to 3 days.